# Elemento null en RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

estoy cargando un `RecyclerView` con datos de SQLite y algo estoy haciendo mal porque si bien me trae los elementos, añade uno con datos nulos. Pensé que podía ser que guardé un elemento vacío pero al quitar y volver a instalar la aplicación, luego de añadir un elemento vuelve a aparecer el elemento `null`.

Así es como llamo los datos:

```
public List<Cartuchos> listaCartuchos(){
    Cartuchos cartuchos = null;
    ArrayList lista = new ArrayList<>();
    this.abrirDBEscribir();
    try (Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " +
            TablaCartuchos.ID_CARTUCHO + ", " +
            TablaCartuchos.MODELO_CARTUCHO  + ", " +
            TablaCartuchos.COLOR_CARTUCHO + ", " +
            TablaCartuchos.CANTIDAD_CARTUCHO  + ", " +
            TablaCartuchos.FECHA_MODIFICACION_CANTIDAD_CARTUCHO
            + " FROM " +
            TablaCartuchos.CARTUCHOS_TABLA , null)) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            cartuchos = new Cartuchos();
            cartuchos.setIdCartucho(cursor.getInt(0));
            cartuchos.setModelo(cursor.getString(1));
            cartuchos.setColor(cursor.getString(2));
            cartuchos.setCantidad(cursor.getInt(3));
            cartuchos.setFechaModificacion(cursor.getString(4));
            lista.add(cartuchos);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.d("listaCart", "listaCartuchos: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    this.cerrarDB();
    return lista;
}
```

Desde mi `Fragment` hago lo siguiente:

```
public class ListadoCartuchos extends Fragment {
    TextView alerta;
    LinearLayout linearAlerta;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewListaCartuchos adaptador;
    View view;
    List<Cartuchos> listaCartuchos = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListadoCartuchos() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listado, container, false);

        listaCartuchos = new ArrayList<>();

        alerta = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAlertaCantidadCartuchos);
        linearAlerta = view.findViewById(R.id.linearAlertaCartucho);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCartuchos);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        listadoCartuchosSQLite();

        adaptador = new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(getActivity(), listaCartuchos, ListadoCartuchos.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
        return view;
    }

    public void listadoCartuchosSQLite(){
        ProcesosSQLite procesosSQLite = new ProcesosSQLite(getContext());
        try{
            listaCartuchos = procesosSQLite.listaCartuchos();
            Cartuchos cartuchos = new Cartuchos();
            int id = cartuchos.getIdCartucho();
            String modelo = cartuchos.getModelo();
            String color = cartuchos.getColor();
            int cantidad = cartuchos.getCantidad();
            String fecha = cartuchos.getFechaModificacion();
            listaCartuchos.add(new Cartuchos(id, modelo, color, fecha, cantidad));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Listado", "listadoCartuchos: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es mi **adaptador**:

```
public class RecyclerViewListaCartuchos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder> {
    List<Cartuchos> mValues;
    Context mContext;
    ListadoCartuchos listadoCartuchos;

    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(Context context, List<Cartuchos> values, ListadoCartuchos listadoCartuchos) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        this.listadoCartuchos = listadoCartuchos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.vista_diseno_cartucho, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder(view, listadoCartuchos);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView idCartucho;
        public TextView modeloColor;
        public TextView tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod;
        public ImageView iv_cartucho_img;
        public View layout;
        Cartuchos item;
        ListadoCartuchos listadoCartuchos;

        public ViewHolder(View v, ListadoCartuchos listadoCartuchos) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            this.listadoCartuchos = listadoCartuchos;

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            cardView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardViewCartucho);
            idCartucho = v.findViewById(R.id.idCartucho);
            modeloColor = v.findViewById(R.id.tvModeloColorCartucho);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod = v.findViewById(R.id.tvFechaModificacionCartucho);
            iv_cartucho_img = v.findViewById(R.id.ivCartuchoImagen);
        }

        public void setData(Cartuchos item) {
            this.item = item;
            String dato = item.getModelo() + " " + item.getColor() + " - Cantidad: " + item.getCantidad();
            String idC = String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho());
            String fec_us = "Última actualización: " + item.getFechaModificacion();
            idCartucho.setText(idC);
            modeloColor.setText(dato);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod.setText(fec_us);            }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {}
            
    }
}
```

¿Alguien ve mi error?

Imagen donde muestro que hay un elemento null en mi recycler view:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando imprimo la lista, en el LogCat esta me devuelve los tres elementos que tengo almacenados en mi BD pero en el recyclerview veo esos tres más uno que está todo en null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes el error desplegado en el LogCAat

Comment: En mi LogCat no hay ningún error desplegado. @Jorgesys

Comment: Ok , tu lista solo tiene 3 elementos pero en el adapter se insertan 4 verdad?

Comment: En efecto, en SQLite solo hay tres valores pero en mi adapter aparecen esos tres más uno en null @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione mi problema realizando los siguientes ajustes, desde mi DBAdapter hice el cursor para devolver la lista:

```
public Cursor traerTodosCartuchos(){
    String[] columnas = {TablaCartuchos.ID_CARTUCHO, TablaCartuchos.MODELO_CARTUCHO,
            TablaCartuchos.COLOR_CARTUCHO, TablaCartuchos.CANTIDAD_CARTUCHO,
            TablaCartuchos.FECHA_MODIFICACION_CANTIDAD_CARTUCHO};
    return sqLiteDatabase.query(TablaCartuchos.CARTUCHOS_TABLA, columnas, null, null, null, null,
             TablaCartuchos.MODELO_CARTUCHO +" ASC, " + TablaCartuchos.COLOR_CARTUCHO + " ASC");
}
```

Y desde mi Fragment lo modifiqué quedando así:

```
public void listadoCartuchosSQLite(){
    listaCartuchos.clear();
    DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getContext());
    dbAdapter.abrirDB();

    Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.traerTodosCartuchos();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String modelo = cursor.getString(1);
        String color = cursor.getString(2);
        int cantidad = cursor.getInt(3);
        String fechaModificacion = cursor.getString(4);

        Cartuchos cartuchos = new Cartuchos(id, modelo, color, cantidad, fechaModificacion);
        listaCartuchos.add(cartuchos);
    }
    if(!(listaCartuchos.size() < 1)){
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
    dbAdapter.cerrarDB();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que posiblemente sucede en este caso es que si existe otro registro en el cursor pero no estas obteniendo sus valores adecuadamente, cuando obtengas los campos del cursor usa `cursor.getColumnIndex(...)`, realiza este cambio:

```
...
...
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            cartuchos = new Cartuchos();

            cartuchos.setIdCartucho(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TablaCartuchos.ID_CARTUCHO)));
            cartuchos.setModelo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TablaCartuchos.MODELO_CARTUCHO)));
            cartuchos.setColor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TablaCartuchos.COLOR_CARTUCHO)));
            cartuchos.setCantidad(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TablaCartuchos.CANTIDAD_CARTUCHO)));
            cartuchos.setFechaModificacion(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TablaCartuchos.FECHA_MODIFICACION_CANTIDAD_CARTUCHO)));

            /*cartuchos.setIdCartucho(cursor.getInt(0));
            cartuchos.setModelo(cursor.getString(1));
            cartuchos.setColor(cursor.getString(2));
            cartuchos.setCantidad(cursor.getInt(3));
            cartuchos.setFechaModificacion(cursor.getString(4));*/
            lista.add(cartuchos);
        }
...
...
```

Comment: Hice lo me sugieres pero me sigue trayendo el null.  :/

Comment: En el flujo de tu aplicaci[on despues de llamar listaCartuchos(), vuelves a  llamar .add() para agregar mas elementos al listado?